# Gitlab runner and flutter_dotenv in CI/CD

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, flutter-packages, flutter-dotenv

I want to build a desktop application for linux with flutter that will be used by clients in a controlled environment, I mean it is not a public app that will be downloaded by anyone.

I've thought about building the app from the Gitlab runners and storing it in the gitlab packages. Then the clients, managed by me, download the new versions through the gitlab api.

I'm using the [flutter_dotenv](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv) package to load environment variables in my flutter app. The documentation recommends adding the `.env` file to the assets and also adding it to the `.gitignore`.

The truth is that in the CI/CD when I build the flutter app that is going to be used in production, it gives an error because the `.env` file does not exist and yet it is being referenced in the assets. This is the error it shows.

[image]

The only thing that occurs to me is from the runner itself to know if I am building for **test** or for **prod** and create the `.env` as appropriate. Obviously there is no other option for testing, but I'm not sure if it's good practice and if it's the responsibility of the gitlab runners to create the **prod** env.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your CI/CD environment is - edit - I see it. GitLab.  If it were Azure - you could upload your .env to local secure files storage and in a step of your CI/CD deployment you could copy it in from secure files to the working directory where your app is being built.  That is how I have dealt with a missing local.properties file for Android deployment from Azure

sample for Azure, maybe can be adapted to GitLab format

```
         - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
        name: local_properties
        displayName: 'Download local properties'
        inputs:
          secureFile: 'local.properties'

      - script: |
          echo Installing $(local_properties.secureFilePath) to the android build folder $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/android ...
          sudo cp $(local_properties.secureFilePath) $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/android
          sudo chown -R $(whoami) /home/vsts/work/1/s/android/local.properties
```

Comment: It could be a solution, but I don't use Azure. Thank you very much.

Comment: I looked and I think GitLab has secure file storage as well.  Perhaps the concept would be usable. Our pipelines proceed normally with it. I'll update my comment with a sample of the copy file code, which is script that would apply to any file